# Convert Control Flow Graph To Directed Acyclic Grraph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, control-flow, control-flow-graph

Let's say I have a cyclic control flow graph

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> G
     ^         |
     |         v
     F <------ E
```

Each node is associated with a cost.
I additionally have a state variable that is modified each time I enter node D. The probability of `D -> E` and `D -> G` is determined by this state variable.

What I want is to enumerate all possible paths (at a certain state `P( D -> G) = 1`), and find the probability and cost for each path.  The first step, I think is transforming this control flow graph with state variable to a directed acyclic graph by unrolling it. Is there a straightforward algorithm for this?  Any libraries (like networkx) that can help?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/90481/how-to-remove-cycles-from-a-directed-graph

> You can always make a digraph acyclic by removing all edges.